# Error in loading a bootstrap ui angular model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular and bootstrap, I have my login.html with LoginController.

I try to create a modal popup window, So in order to do it i need to add $modal to the controller, the current controller looks like:

```
angular.module('loginController', ['loginService'])
 .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService', function($scope, LoginService) {
```

But when i do:

```
angular.module('loginController', ['loginService','ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal','LoginService', function($scope, $modal,LoginService) {
```

I Received an error, and i am getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module loginController due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I guess i need to add bootstrap-ui somewhere, maybe to:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'bootstrap-ui',   -> **when i add it, i still get the exception**.
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you show us your html? Have you added `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js`

Comment: I Am taking reference from another project, that project did not use ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js

Comment: You need to add a ui-bootstrap-*.js . And of course you need to declare it on your module as you did.

Comment: I thought it was inside bootstrap js, but i suspected also what you have said and when i searched the references project for string ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js i could not find it since they references ui-bootstrap-tpls.js.. Thanks alot - works

Comment: Good to know it helped. I moved it to the answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference one of `ui-bootstrap-*.js` files in your `html`.